# Bigram analysis and Term document Matrix

Tags: r, n-gram, naivebayes, text-analysis

I am.doing a bigram analyis on my text corpus. My feature vector is a predefined set of bigram and unigram tokens.

**Feature vector** = ( good location, bad experience, clean, unfriendly, tidy, excellent, beautiful place)

**my text** :  location is good but unfriendly staff.

**Cleaned text :** location good unfriendly staff.

I created a tdf using the above dictionary and cleaned text but the "location good" bigram is not giving a "1". 
But when I changed the cleaned text to  "good location unfriendly staff".
In a bigram analysis do the order of the words matter and why ? or am i messing up with the code ? Kindly clarify

"bad experience"    "tidy"  "clean" "good location" "excellent" "beautiful" "place" "unfriendly"

0   0   0   0   0   0   1 -- location good but  unfriendly staff.

0   0   0   1   0   0   1  --  good location but  unfriendly staff.

Comment: it should be dependant on what model you're using, but usually, the ordering of the words does matter.

Comment: Thanks Aramis..I  am using naive bayes bernoulli document model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my experience goes the order of words in n-grams is critical. You would not want to consider the n-grams 'Putin attacked' and "attacked Putin" to be the same as they have very different contextual meaning.

So no you are not messing up the code. You just may want to do a little more research into n-gram models. A good start may be with [Chapter 4 in Speech and Language Processing by Jurafsky and Martin](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf)